# How do I add a JsonIgnore attribute to all properties with a specific return type in a class using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, properties, roslyn, class-members

In the following code only one property is updated at a time and previously updated properties are ignored. I know that syntax nodes are immutable so I'm missing something. What I end up with is that only the last replaced property is updated. What am I missing?

```
var newMemberDeclarations = new SyntaxList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>();
newMemberDeclarations.AddRange(@class.Members);

foreach (var prop in props)
{
    var oldProperty = (PropertyDeclarationSyntax)prop;
    // e.g. Customer or ICollection<Customer>
    if (oldProperty.Type.Kind() == SyntaxKind.IdentifierName ||
        oldProperty.Type.Kind() == SyntaxKind.GenericName)
    {
        var memberAttributes = new SyntaxList<AttributeListSyntax>().AddRange(oldProperty.AttributeLists).Add(jsonIgnoreAttribute);
        var newProperty = SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(
                            memberAttributes,
                            oldProperty.Modifiers,
                            oldProperty.Type,
                            oldProperty.ExplicitInterfaceSpecifier,
                            oldProperty.Identifier,
                            oldProperty.AccessorList
                            );
        var replaced = @class.Members.Replace(oldProperty, newProperty);
        // This ignores previously updated property 
        // and only adds the attribute on the last replaced property
        newMemberDeclarations.AddRange(replaced);                        
     }
}
```

```
var attributes = @class.AttributeLists.AddRange(attributeLists);
root = root.ReplaceNode(@class, @class.WithAttributeLists(attributes))
           .AddUsings(usingSerialization, usingCollections, usingJson)
           .WithMembers(newMemberDeclarations)
           .NormalizeWhitespace();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            foreach (var classDeclaration in classDeclarations)
            {
                var @class = classDeclaration as ClassDeclarationSyntax;

                List<AttributeListSyntax> attributeLists = new List<AttributeListSyntax>();
                attributeLists.Add(serializableAttribute);

                var guidTypeSyntax = SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(typeof(Guid).FullName) as QualifiedNameSyntax;
                var dateTimeTypeSyntax = SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(typeof(DateTime).FullName) as QualifiedNameSyntax;
                
                var customTypes = @class.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x is PropertyDeclarationSyntax)
                    .Select(x => (PropertyDeclarationSyntax)x)
                    .Where(x => x.Type.Kind() == SyntaxKind.IdentifierName || x.Type.Kind() == SyntaxKind.GenericName)
                    ;
                
                customTypes.ToList().ForEach(t => // .Type.GetType().FullName
                {
                    bool isGuid = ((IdentifierNameSyntax)t.Type).Identifier.Value == guidTypeSyntax.Right.Identifier.Value;
                    bool isDateTime = ((IdentifierNameSyntax)t.Type).Identifier.Value == dateTimeTypeSyntax.Right.Identifier.Value;
                    
                    if (t.Type is GenericNameSyntax)
                    {
                        var args = ((GenericNameSyntax)t.Type).TypeArgumentList.Arguments;
                        foreach(var arg in args)
                        {
                            if(arg is IdentifierNameSyntax)
                            {
                                if (!(isGuid || isDateTime))
                                {
                                    var type = ((IdentifierNameSyntax)arg).Identifier.Value.ToString();
                                    var attribute = CreateKnownTypeAttribute(type);
                                    var knownTypeEntityHashSetAttribute = CreateKnownTypeAttribute($"HashSet<{type}>");
                                    attributeLists.Add(knownTypeEntityHashSetAttribute);
                                    attributeLists.Add(attribute);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    else if(t.Type is IdentifierNameSyntax)
                    {
                        if (!(isGuid || isDateTime))
                        {
                            var identifier = ((IdentifierNameSyntax)t.Type).Identifier.Value.ToString();
                            var attribute = CreateKnownTypeAttribute(identifier);
                            var knownTypeEntityHashSetAttribute = CreateKnownTypeAttribute($"HashSet<{identifier}>");
                            attributeLists.Add(knownTypeEntityHashSetAttribute);
                            attributeLists.Add(attribute);
                        }
                    }
                });

                var members = new SyntaxList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(@class.Members);
                
                customTypes.ToList().ForEach(oldProperty =>
                {
                    var memberAttributes = new SyntaxList<AttributeListSyntax>().AddRange(oldProperty.AttributeLists).Add(jsonIgnoreAttribute);
                    var newProperty = SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaration(
                        memberAttributes,
                        oldProperty.Modifiers,
                        oldProperty.Type,
                        oldProperty.ExplicitInterfaceSpecifier,
                        oldProperty.Identifier,
                        oldProperty.AccessorList
                        ) as MemberDeclarationSyntax;

                    if (oldProperty.Type is IdentifierNameSyntax)
                    {
                        bool isGuid = ((IdentifierNameSyntax)oldProperty.Type).Identifier.Value == guidTypeSyntax.Right.Identifier.Value;
                        bool isDateTime = ((IdentifierNameSyntax)oldProperty.Type).Identifier.Value == dateTimeTypeSyntax.Right.Identifier.Value;
                        bool isInt = oldProperty.Type.Kind() == SyntaxKind.IntKeyword;
                        bool isFloat = oldProperty.Type.Kind() == SyntaxKind.FloatKeyword;

                        if (!(isGuid || isDateTime))
                        {
                            var identifier = oldProperty.Identifier.Value;
                            var indexOf = members.IndexOf(m => m is PropertyDeclarationSyntax ? ((PropertyDeclarationSyntax)m).Identifier.Value == identifier : false);
                            members = members.RemoveAt(indexOf).Add(newProperty);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(oldProperty.Type is GenericNameSyntax)
                    {
                        var identifier = oldProperty.Identifier.Value;
                        var indexOf = members.IndexOf(m => m is PropertyDeclarationSyntax 
                           ? ((PropertyDeclarationSyntax)m).Identifier.Value == identifier : false);
                        members = members.RemoveAt(indexOf).Add(newProperty);
                    }
                });

                var attributes = @class.AttributeLists.AddRange(attributeLists);
                var c = SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration(@class.Identifier)
                    .WithBaseList(@class.BaseList)
                    .AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword), 
                                  SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword))
                    .WithAttributeLists(attributes)
                    .AddMembers(members.ToArray());

                root = root.ReplaceNode(@class, c)
                    .AddUsings(usingSerialization, usingCollections, usingSerialisation)
                    .NormalizeWhitespace();
            }
```